# Angularjs minify best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm reading  http://www.alexrothenberg.com/2013/02/11/the-magic-behind-angularjs-dependency-injection.html and
it turned out that angularjs dependency injection has problems if you minify your javascript
so I'm wondering if instead of

```
var MyController = function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js/commits')
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.commits = response.data
      })
  }
```

you should use

```
var MyController = ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js/commits')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.commits = response.data
    })
}]
```

all in all I thought the second snippet was for the old version of angularjs but ....

Should I always use the inject way (the second one) ?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**Yes**, always! So this way even if your minifer converts $scope to variable a and $http to variable b, their **identity is still preserved** in the strings.

See [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) of AngularJS docs, scroll down to **[A Note on Minification](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#a-note-on-minification)**.

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, you can use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) npm package in your build process to avoid this verbosity.

Comment: This, and some other issues are very good explained at egghead.io. JFYI

Comment: @Sprottenwels: Yup! Lot of useful resources there.

Comment: Instead of using this more verbose syntax you can use ngmin and a build tool (like Grunt)  before you run minification. That way you can minify properly but also use either dependency injection syntax.

Comment: A note on minification have been moved here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: See also [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation).

Answer (score 37):

It is safer to use the second variant but it is also possible to use the first variant safely with [ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin).

**UPDATE:**
Now [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) becomes a new default tool to solve this issue.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you need to use **explicit** dependency injection (second variant). But since [Angular 1.3.1](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) you can **turn off implicit** dependency injection, it's really helpful to solve potential problems with renaming at once (before minification).

Turning off implicit DI, using `strictDi` config property:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'], {
    strictDi: true
});
```

Turning off implicit DI, using `ng-strict-di` directive:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Just to point out that if you use**

[Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)

there is no need to do like

```
var MyController = ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js/commits')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.commits = response.data
    })
}]
```

because  grunt during minify take into account how to manage DI.

Answer (score 1):

Like OZ_ said, Use ngmin to minify all angular js file, like directive.js service.js. After that you can use Closure compiler to optimize it.

ref:

[How to minify angularjs scripts](http://chrislarson.me/blog/how-minify-angularjs-scripts)

[Build with YO](http://chrislarson.me/blog/angularjs-yeoman-grunt-and-bower)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `$inject` as it mentioned [here](http://frontendcollisionblog.com/javascript/angularjs/2015/03/31/something-no-one-tells-you-about-minifying-angularjs-controllers-until-its-too-late.html):

```
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function MyController($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js/commits')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.commits = response.data
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use Strict Dependency Injection to Diagnose Problems

With [Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation), code will break when minified.

From the Docs:

> ## Implicit Annotation
>
> > **Careful:** If you plan to minify your code, your service names will get renamed and break your app.

You can add an `ng-strict-di` directive on the same element as `ng-app` to opt into strict DI mode.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```

**Strict mode throws an error whenever a service tries to use implicit annotations.**

This can be useful to determining finding problems.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using Strict Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection)
- [AngularJS ng-app Directive API Reference](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/docs/api/ng/directive/ngApp)
- [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)