# gruntfile.js issues or minification issues

Tags: firebase

We are working on developing a website using different APIs naming Firebase, Filepicker etc. Technologies used are Node.js and AngularJS. The project is based on a tool called yeoman, which is a scaffolding tool for web apps. We keep our modules updated through bower and NPM. The website is developed and running fine locally. We are inclined to host the app on Heroku's server and whenever we push the production code the application breaks without any message and the server crashes. I believe there are some issues with Gruntfile.js or minification issues with angular when used with grunt. Please connect me with someone who could guide me to setup the website on Heroku's server. We use heroku toolbelt for windows to push the changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues with minifying AngularJS app, some of the declarations need to be written in particular way. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice).

Also, read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05), scroll down to the part "A note on minification".

I've found [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-yeomanangular-app-heroku/) when looking for Heroku + AngularJS issues.

Please also verify compression server settings you are using.