# Unknown provider: eProvider <- e when showing material angular dialog

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

I'm trying to get [material angular](https://material.angularjs.org)'s dialog wired up. Code below. I get error, `Unknown provider: eProvider <- e`.

**Js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

var dialogController = app.controller('dialogController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.hide = function () {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };
    $scope.answer = function (answer) {
        $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };
}]);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.showDialog = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: dialogController,
            templateUrl: 'sign-in.html',
            targetEvent: e
        });
    };
}]);
```

**Html**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="showDialog($event)">Show dialog</a>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="sign-in.html">
    hello there
</script>
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

var dialogController = function($scope, $mdDialog) {
   $scope.hide = function () {
      $mdDialog.hide();
   };
   $scope.cancel = function () {
      $mdDialog.cancel();
   };
   $scope.answer = function (answer) {
       $mdDialog.hide(answer);
   };
};

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.showDialog = function (e) {

      $mdDialog.show({
         controller: dialogController,
         templateUrl: 'sign-in.html',
         targetEvent: e
      });
   };
}]);
```

HTML call it like this :

```
 <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="showDialog($event)">Show dialog</md-button>
```

Comment: I get "Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Whoops, I was just doing a <a href="#" ng-click="showDialog($event)">Show dialog</a> and _not_ doing the <md-button>. This fixed it, thanks so much!

Comment: The dialog is showing up, but I'm still getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined". Maybe b/c my template contents are missing something, I wonder?

Comment: I copy/pasted the example from the custom dialog template on angular material website, and that did the trick. I had to add in showDialog($event) in my html. If you can update your answer to have that $event, I'll mark as correct! https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.dialog

Comment: You can't do a href & ng-click at the same time. And i have updated html with showDialog($event)

Comment: What's with the random ']' with no '[' in dialogController?

Comment: @Laser : those are for safe minification. Annotating the function with the names of the dependencies as strings makes sure that these are not minified.
Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice

Comment: @nitin is it not a typo to have a closing bracket ']' with no opening bracket '[' though? As it's not clear where the opening bracket would go, and it seems that the controller may need this syntax but not functions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add single quotes to the controller name:

```
$mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'dialogController',
    templateUrl: 'sign-in.html',
    targetEvent: e
});
```

**Edit:** 
I have one thing to update, I know why the error "'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined" happens. You have to use this script as template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="sign-in.html">
    <md-dialog> 
        <md-content>Hello there</md-content> 
    </md-dialog>    
</script>
```

And btw, my answer about the single quotes should work at the first time. Try it again with this new template.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined.

Comment: Then please  check if "locals" attribute is need, and provided it properly. Because I find a similar error in this example, when I remove the "locals" : http://codepen.io/ThomasBurleson/pen/qEBJME

Comment: After providing locals: {} I get Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object

Comment: sorry, now I see _locals_ with empty object is unnecessary. About the "getBoundingClientRect" error, please check my update.