# Angular Controllers - Annotations

Tags: angularjs, controller

just saw 2 different demos and they differ some in the code.
What is the reason for the two different approaches?

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', function($scope, $mdDialog){
  //Code goes here
}]);
```

and

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog){
  //Code goes here
});
```

As I understand it the first one is to recommend in case of I'm to use minification.. but is there other reasons to consider?

Comment: It expands upon the minification use case, but when you intend your code to be re-usable as a library / module, the annotated version (so the first) is considered the best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first syntax is minification-safe.

If you minify the second syntax, you will get for your controller :

```
function(a,b){...};
```

And you will then get errors.

Note that you can use build plugins like **[ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)** that will transform your code from the second syntax to the first, thus will make your code *minification-safe*. That's why it is more convenient to go with the second syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Both are ways to use Dependency injection, you can read [angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) on that matter.

Basically, on the options you just mentioned:

1. **Option 1 - Inline Array Annotation** - Here we pass an array whose elements consist of a list of strings (the names of the dependencies) followed by the function itself.
2. **Option 2 - Implicit Annotation** - you assume that the function parameter names are the names of the dependencies

Option 1 is safe to minify.
See related post - [Why implicit annotation are not safe to minify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice)