# how to use a Modal in my simple AngularJs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not able to load the modal service into my simple rookie angular controller example, I've included the plunker below.  Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?  any help much appreciated!
Thanks

http://plnkr.co/edit/VVyMsRMVg5DzeqpnvWSQ?p=preview

**code snippet**

```
  app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'FService', 'angularModalService', function($scope, FService, angularModalService) {


  $scope.show = function() {
    angularModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: "ModalController"
    }).then(function(modal) {
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function(result) {
            $scope.message = "You said " + result;
        });
    });
  };
  }
```

Comment: Since you're using ui-bootstrap, here's another plunker that might provide you with insights and some added features http://plnkr.co/edit/FK9o5DWOqxmePZJEW75v?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this very helpful. Hope you do too.

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service

Comment: Be carefull with that code, after minification will not work unless using minification best practices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice