# Minifying AngularJS script that includes a custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

I've looked at three different ways to minify AngularJS scripts. However, none of them explains how I'm supposed to take into account custom filters. I have my code formatted like this:

```
app.controller("App", ["$scope","$timeout", function($scope, $timeout){...}]);
```

Along with some additional code like this:

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

When I minify all of the above, the filter isn't recognized anymore. How do I go about prepping my code for minification?

Comment: Look how you've defined `App`. Use same syntax for `unsafe` filter.

Comment: u have added $sce service in ur filter while minifying the $sce will get changed into some alphabet name so u need to add dependencies in array.so angular could not be able to find tat service.

Comment: See [Why we Inject our dependencies two times in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390338/why-we-inject-our-dependencies-two-times-in-angularjs)

Comment: app.filter('unsafe',['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
}]);

Comment: Whenever you want minification, you must annotate your function like you did for App controller because after the process $sce will be named with some other name and angular wont know how to inject that thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
app.filter('unsafe', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
}]);
```

When minified that **$sce** is transformed in a variable called **a** so that it takes less space possible but angular doesn't recognize it anymore so you need to declare that that first parameter is still $sce but with another variable name