# $injector.unpr error in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS JavaScript. Just started learning it. I was trying with some small sample programs. Here is what I tried but its throwing error.

```js
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    {{time}}
    <br>
  </div>
</body>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  app.service('hexafy', ['',
    function() {
      this.myfunc = function(num) {
        return num.toString(16);
      }
    }
  ]);

  app.controller('myCtrl', ['hexafy', '$scope', '$interval',
    function(hexafy, $scope, $interval) {
      $scope.time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      $interval(function() {
        $scope.time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      }, 1000);
      // $scope.hex = hexafy.myfunc(255);
    }
  ]);
</script>
```

Comment: `app.service('hexafy', ['', function() {` ==> `app.service('hexafy', function() {`

Comment: use an unminified version of angular.js to see described errors!

Comment: @Tushar Your given code resolve the problem of OP. Shouldn't it be added as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array syntax is used when the code is minified and keep the mapping of arguments. For more on this please see my other answer [Why we Inject our dependencies two times in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390338/why-we-inject-our-dependencies-two-times-in-angularjs).

In the code, as there is no parameter passed to the `hexafy` service, there is no need of using the array syntax and pass empty string.

```
app.service('hexafy', ['',
    function() {
```

Use normal syntax.

```
app.service('hexafy', function() { // <-- Remove `[` and empty string from here
    ...
    ...
}); // <-- Remove `]` from here
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.service('hexafy', function() {
  this.myfunc = function(num) {
    return num.toString(16);
  }
});

app.controller('myCtrl', ['hexafy', '$scope', '$interval',
  function(hexafy, $scope, $interval) {
    $scope.time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    $interval(function() {
      $scope.time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    }, 1000);
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{ time }}
    <br />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What Tushar has suggested is perfect, Just adding working piece of [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pc7CHAGTooSs758gEGL3?p=preview)

```
app.service('hexafy',function() {
  this.myfunc = function(num) {
    return num.toString(16);
  }
 }
);
```

Comment: `Just adding working piece of Plunker`, should it be added as new answer? Tushar has already added working example.

Comment: @KhalidHussain Yes. This answer shows the correct code, a working example. Also, he has added attribution.