# AngularJS Controller's constructor function declaration significance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am new to AngularJs. While learning ,i am seeing these two types of controller declarations.

Can you guys just tell me the significance of each type mentioned below.

**Type 1:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('DoubleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.letter="A";
}]);
```

**Type 2:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('DoubleController', [ function($scope) {
$scope.letter="A";
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first type (recommended type), the string `"$scope"` is used for minification purposes - all arguments are shortend to one or two characters. Strings are not minified, therefore Angular will use this string when injecting to the controller. Look at this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18782380/5954939