# Angular js minify errors

Tags: angularjs

When I try to minify the following code it breaks. What's wrong? What's the simplest way to fix this?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('weatherapp.weatherlist')
    .controller('WeatherlistController2', function($scope, utcFactory) { 
        var vm = this; 
        vm.utc = utcFactory.myUTC(); 
     })

    .factory('utcFactory', function() {
        var myUTC = function() {
          var offset = -new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
          var utc = ((offset > 0 ? '+' : '') + offset / 60);
          return utc;
        }

        return {
          myUTC: myUTC
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: First, what errors? Also, why are you injecting `$scope` if you're not even using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem. Use the array syntax for your controller:

```
.controller('WeatherlistController2', [ '$scope', 'utcFactory', function($scope, utcFactory) {}])
```

See here as well: [Angularjs minify best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice)

Comment: Why does minification break this?

Comment: By the way @AgentZebra, there are tools that will do this for you automatically as part of your build step, if you have one. gulp-ng-annotate, for example.

Comment: Minification breaks this because if you don't use the syntax that is mentioned above, angular literally calls the .toString() method on your controller function to determine what dependencies are being injected into your controller (in this case, $scope and utcFactory). When you minify your code, $scope and utcFactory are going to be minimized into random variabled like a or b, so when angular parses your function as text, it won't be able to inject 'a' or 'b', and then your whole application won't work. See http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/angularjs-dependency-injection-demystified/

Comment: Just to add: Minifiers usually have a name mangling option. If that option is on, function parameters are changed to random variables like `a` or `b` ....

Comment: @AminMeyghani Thanks, I figured this one out, how do you turn the name mangler on and off?

Comment: @matmo what does a good production build step look like? What tools / steps would you use / include?

Comment: @AgentZebra I did a [quick write up](https://gist.github.com/Matmo10/ae272de2513749f327a90cb2e1c57b1b) of the way I do things personally...I'm not claiming its the best way but it works (there are lots of people with strong opinions in the frontend ecosystem). Feel free to ask any further questions you have.

Comment: @matmo Thank you so much this is really very helpful.