# Gulp minified js throws error

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify, gulp-minify

We have lots of separate JavaScript files, and of course they are minified into various others in Production. Currently we use [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) from command line for this task, but the intention is to switch to [gulpjs](http://gulpjs.com/).

The minification process itself *seems* to be okay, all the output files are generated, no error is written to output, etc.

But I have a weird issue, ~4-5 out of 16 minified files generated by `gulpjs` throw various errors, such as:

> Cannot read property '...' of undefined

or

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is not a function

Ajax minifier is called as follows:

```
AjaxMin.exe -js -xml .\minify.xml -clobber -evals:safeall
```

A sample from the `minify.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
      <output path="..\js\min\main.min.js">
        <input path="..\js\filename1.js"/>
        <input path="..\js\filename2.js"/>
        <input path="..\js\filename3.js"/>
        ...
      </output>
      <output path="..\js\min\report.min.js">
        <input path="..\js\filename4.js"/>
        <input path="..\js\filename5.js"/>
        <input path="..\js\filename6.js"/>
        ...
      </output>
      ...
    </root>
```

A sample from `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task("[js]minify-all", function () {
    var mainFiles = [
        "./js/filename1.js",
        "./js/filename2.js",
        "./js/filename3.js",
    ];
    var reportFiles = [
        "./js/filename4.js",
        "./js/filename5.js",
        "./js/filename6.js",
    ];
    ...
    generateMinifiedFile(mainFiles, "./js/min/", "main");
    generateMinifiedFile(reportFiles, "./js/min/", "report");
    ...
}

var generateMinifiedFile = function(inputFiles, outputPath, outputFileName) {
    gulp.src(inputFiles)
        .pipe(concat(outputFileName + ".js"))
        .pipe(minify({
            ext: {
                min: ".min.js"
            },
            noSource: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputPath));
};
```

In case it matters, here's `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-bower": "0.0.13",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-config": "0.3.0",
    "gulp-less": "3.0.5",
    "gulp-minify": "0.0.12",
    "gulp-minify-css": "1.2.4",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5"
  }
}
```

To sum it up:

- Using non-minified js files, the site works fine.
- Using minified js files created by `AjaxMin.exe`, the site works fine.
- Using minified js files created by `gulpjs`, the site breaks.

Anyone has a suggestion what I miss?

**UPDATE**

Sample of creating a controller:

```
var settingsModule = angular.module("settingsModule", ["rootModule"]);
settingsModule.controller('settingsCasesController', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$http", "DataService", function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, dataService) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you use Angular may be in your sources?

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov yes, angular files are direct references on the pages, so they're not minified into any of the output files

Comment: Do you minify your angular directives? If so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov yes, they _should_ be safe (I'll have to check it out to give a 100% sure answer), but wouldn't it be an issue using AjaxMin too?

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov double checked, angular directives are minification safe

Comment: How do you inject your dependencies? Are you using $inject? Can you show example directive?

Comment: @yariash I updated the question with a js sample for creating a controller

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This should be a comment, but It is an answer since it's a bit long, and an answer is easyer to write and to read...*

To start with, I'd try setting to `false` both `gulp-minify` options `mangle` and `compress`.

If code runs ok, you should try setting to `false` only one option, to see which one is responsible of the failure.

If code breaks (this would be quite strange, since I suppose the main task of a minifier is to compress and to mangle...), I'd try to manually compare the output of one `gulp-minify`ed file to the source, to see what are the changes...

Comment: I set `compress` and `mangle` to false, but I still have the same issue

Comment: I'd try to manually compare the output of one gulp-minifyed file to the source, to see what are the changes, and from those changes, trace back to the root problem.

Comment: One more question: does your code pass a jslint check?

Comment: Since many legacy files are involved, I blindly say they don't pass. On the other hand, shouldn't it be an issue for AjaxMin as well?

Comment: It's possible (well, it's quite sure... :-) the two minifiers sport different levels of strictness, or even different language standards compliance levels... :-(