# Why are some components defined in an array, where others aren't?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Edit: Thanks to deoD for pointing me to the right place - this is a duplicate of [Angularjs minify best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice)

---

I feel like this must be a pretty simple thing, but I don't know the name of it and Googling hasn't turned up much :/

Some Ionic tutorials that I've seen define controllers (and factories, etc) like this to inject a dependency

```
angular.module( 'x' )
    .controller( 'XController', function( $scope ) {
        // ...
    } );
```

And some define it like this

```
angular.module( 'x' )
    .controller( 'XController', [ '$scope',
        function( $scope ) {
            // ...
        }
    ] );
```

What's the difference between the two, and if that doesn't answer the following question, when would you use one over the other?

Comment: this would answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice  (basically it is best practice for js minification)

Comment: @deoD thanks - I knew it must have been asked, but since I didn't know what it was trying to solve, I couldn't find it :) Voting to close this since it's a duplicate, thanks

Comment: This is basically implicit vs explicit dependency injection;  you should only really use implicit injection in quick example snippets, never in live production code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just go ahead and read more about it on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di as Ionic is based on AngularJS.

Using minified version looks simpler and cleaner for me :

```
 myApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $route, $http,$cookies,$timeout){
    //..
 });
```