# templateUrl is not working after minification

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gruntjs, minify

I have a website that i built with yeoman angular-fullstack.  I am trying to minify the project and for the most part it works.  The only issue I have is I have a popup dialog that isnt working.  I have narrowed the problem down to the `templateUrl` command when calling on the material dialog.

controller:

```
 function openLoginDialog(ev) {

            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'loginCtrl',
                templateUrl: '../../Dialogs/loginDialog/loginDialog.html',
                targetEvent: ev,
                locals: {
                    createAccount: false,
                    charterID: null
                },
                clickOutsideToClose: true
            });

        }
```

The application is also using grunt.  I belive the problem is the templateUrl's path no longer exists due to the minification.  I can not however, figure out how to get around this issue and have been banging my head on a wall.  I have attempted to use templateCache, but there is no way to inject all the html into the cache.  I would have to copy and paste it into a javascript file and that is not maintainable.  I attempted to use the script tags like so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="loginDialogId.tpl">
<!---- HTML CONTENT ---->
</script>
```

and then call the file byt `templateCahce.get('loginDialogId');` but that did not work.  I have a feeling I have to do something in the grunt file with ngTemplate but I have no idea how to do it and I cannot find any documentation that makes sense.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the grunt file:

```
    // Generated on 2016-06-17 using generator-angular-fullstack 3.7.5
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var localConfig;
  try {
    localConfig = require('./server/config/local.env');
  } catch(e) {
    localConfig = {};
  }

  // Load grunt tasks automatically, when needed
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    express: 'grunt-express-server',
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
    protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
    buildcontrol: 'grunt-build-control',
    istanbul_check_coverage: 'grunt-mocha-istanbul',
    ngconstant: 'grunt-ng-constant'
  });

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({
    // Project settings
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      client: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
      server: 'server',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    express: {
      options: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 9000
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: '<%= yeoman.server %>',
          debug: true
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          script: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.server %>'
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      babel: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).js'],
        tasks: ['newer:babel:client']
      },
      ngconstant: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/config/environment/shared.js'],
        tasks: ['ngconstant']
      },
      injectJS: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.js'
        ],
        tasks: ['injector:scripts']
      },
      injectCss: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['injector:css']
      },
      mochaTest: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.{spec,integration}.js'],
        tasks: ['env:test', 'mochaTest']
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/*.{spec,mock}.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'wiredep:test', 'karma']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        files: [
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/*.{css,html}',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      express: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.{js,json}'],
        tasks: ['express:dev', 'wait'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          spawn: false //Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
        }
      },
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.client %>/.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.server %>/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/!(*.spec|*.integration).js']
      },
      serverTest: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.server %>/.jshintrc-spec'
        },
        src: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.{spec,integration}.js']
      },
      all: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock|app.constant).js'],
      test: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/*.{spec,mock}.js']
      }
    },


    jscs: {
      options: {
        config: ".jscsrc"
      },
      main: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/!(.git*|.openshift|Procfile)**'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    postcss: {
      options: {
        map: true,
        processors: [
          require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 2 version']})
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Debugging with node inspector
    'node-inspector': {
      custom: {
        options: {
          'web-host': 'localhost'
        }
      }
    },

    // Use nodemon to run server in debug mode with an initial breakpoint
    nodemon: {
      debug: {
        script: '<%= yeoman.server %>',
        options: {
          nodeArgs: ['--debug-brk'],
          env: {
            PORT: process.env.PORT || 9000
          },
          callback: function(nodemon) {
            nodemon.on('log', function(event) {
              console.log(event.colour);
            });

            // opens browser on initial server start
            nodemon.on('config:update', function() {
              setTimeout(function() {
                require('open')('http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858');
              }, 500);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app and karma.conf.js
    wiredep: {
      options: {
        exclude: [
          /bootstrap.js/,
          '/json3/',
          '/es5-shim/'
        ]
      },
      client: {
        src: '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html',
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.client %>/'
      },
      test: {
        src: './karma.conf.js',
        devDependencies: true
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/!(bower_components){,*/}*.{js,css}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>'
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/{,!(bower_components)/**/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/!(bower_components){,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/!(bower_components){,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/assets'
        ],
        // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
        patterns: {
          css: [
            [/(assets\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the CSS to reference our revved images']
          ],
          js: [
            [/(assets\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/assets'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
    // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
    ngAnnotate: {

      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat',
          src: '**/*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Dynamically generate angular constant `appConfig` from
    // `server/config/environment/shared.js`
    ngconstant: {
      options: {
        name: 'fndParyBoatsApp.constants',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.constant.js',
        deps: [],
        wrap: true,
        configPath: '<%= yeoman.server %>/config/environment/shared'
      },
      app: {
        constants: function() {
          return {
            appConfig: require('./' + grunt.config.get('ngconstant.options.configPath'))
          };
        }
      }
    },

    // Package all the html partials into a single javascript payload
    ngtemplates: {
      options: {
        // This should be the name of your apps angular module
        module: 'fndParyBoatsApp',
        htmlmin: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
        },
        usemin: 'app/app.js'
      },
      main: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        src: ['{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/templates.js'
      },
      tmp: {
        cwd: '.tmp',
        src: ['{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/tmp-templates.js'
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'bower_components/**/*',
            'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'assets/icons/**/*',
            'index.html'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/assets',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            'package.json',
            '<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.server %>/config/local.env.sample.js'
          ]
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        dest: '.tmp/',
        src: ['{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/*.css']
      }
    },

    buildcontrol: {
      options: {
        dir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        commit: true,
        push: true,
        connectCommits: false,
        message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
      },
      heroku: {
        options: {
          remote: 'heroku',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      },
      openshift: {
        options: {
          remote: 'openshift',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      pre: [
        'ngconstant'
      ],
      server: [
        'newer:babel:client'
      ],
      test: [
        'newer:babel:client'
      ],
      debug: {
        tasks: [
          'nodemon',
          'node-inspector'
        ],
        options: {
          logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
      },
      dist: [
        'newer:babel:client',
        'imagemin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },

    mochaTest: {
      options: {
        reporter: 'spec',
        require: 'mocha.conf.js',
        timeout: 5000 // set default mocha spec timeout
      },
      unit: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.spec.js']
      },
      integration: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.integration.js']
      }
    },

    mocha_istanbul: {
      unit: {
        options: {
          excludes: ['**/*.{spec,mock,integration}.js'],
          reporter: 'spec',
          require: ['mocha.conf.js'],
          mask: '**/*.spec.js',
          coverageFolder: 'coverage/server/unit'
        },
        src: '<%= yeoman.server %>'
      },
      integration: {
        options: {
          excludes: ['**/*.{spec,mock,integration}.js'],
          reporter: 'spec',
          require: ['mocha.conf.js'],
          mask: '**/*.integration.js',
          coverageFolder: 'coverage/server/integration'
        },
        src: '<%= yeoman.server %>'
      }
    },

    istanbul_check_coverage: {
      default: {
        options: {
          coverageFolder: 'coverage/**',
          check: {
            lines: 80,
            statements: 80,
            branches: 80,
            functions: 80
          }
        }
      }
    },

    protractor: {
      options: {
        configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
      },
      chrome: {
        options: {
          args: {
            browser: 'chrome'
          }
        }
      }
    },

    env: {
      test: {
        NODE_ENV: 'test'
      },
      prod: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      },
      all: localConfig
    },

    // Compiles ES6 to JavaScript using Babel
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
      client: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
          src: ['{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/!(*.spec).js'],
          dest: '.tmp'
        }]
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          plugins: [
            'transform-class-properties',
            'transform-runtime'
          ]
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.server %>',
          src: [
            '**/*.js',
            '!config/local.env.sample.js'
          ],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.server %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    injector: {
      options: {},
      // Inject application script files into index.html (doesn't include bower)
      scripts: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            var yoClient = grunt.config.get('yeoman.client');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/' + yoClient + '/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
          },
          sort: function(a, b) {
            var module = /\.module\.(js|ts)$/;
            var aMod = module.test(a);
            var bMod = module.test(b);
            // inject *.module.js first
            return (aMod === bMod) ? 0 : (aMod ? -1 : 1);
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
               [
                 '<%= yeoman.client %>/{services,app,components,Dialogs}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).js',
                 '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/app/app.{js,ts}'
               ]
            ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component css into index.html
      css: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            var yoClient = grunt.config.get('yeoman.client');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/' + yoClient + '/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath + '">';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components,Dialogs,services}/**/*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
  grunt.registerTask('wait', function() {
    grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

    var done = this.async();

    setTimeout(function() {
      grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
      done();
    }, 1500);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('express-keepalive', 'Keep grunt running', function() {
    this.async();
  });

  grunt.registerTask('serve', function(target) {
    if(target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'env:all', 'env:prod', 'express:prod', 'wait', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
    }

    if(target === 'debug') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'concurrent:pre',
        'concurrent:server',
        'injector',
        'wiredep:client',
        'postcss',
        'concurrent:debug'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'env:all',
      'concurrent:pre',
      'concurrent:server',
      'injector',
      'wiredep:client',
      'postcss',
      'express:dev',
      'wait',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function() {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function(target, option) {
    if(target === 'server') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'mochaTest:unit',
        'mochaTest:integration'
      ]);
    } else if(target === 'client') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'concurrent:pre',
        'concurrent:test',
        'injector',
        'postcss',
        'wiredep:test',
        'karma'
      ]);
    } else if(target === 'e2e') {
      if(option === 'prod') {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'build',
          'env:all',
          'env:prod',
          'express:prod',
          'protractor'
        ]);
      } else {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'clean:server',
          'env:all',
          'env:test',
          'concurrent:pre',
          'concurrent:test',
          'injector',
          'wiredep:client',
          'postcss',
          'express:dev',
          'protractor'
        ]);
      }
    } else if(target === 'coverage') {
      if(option === 'unit') {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'env:all',
          'env:test',
          'mocha_istanbul:unit'
        ]);
      } else if(option === 'integration') {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'env:all',
          'env:test',
          'mocha_istanbul:integration'
        ]);
      } else if(option === 'check') {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'istanbul_check_coverage'
        ]);
      } else {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'env:all',
          'env:test',
          'mocha_istanbul',
          'istanbul_check_coverage'
        ]);
      }
    } else {
      grunt.task.run([
        'test:server',
        'test:client'
      ]);
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'concurrent:pre',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'injector',
    'wiredep:client',
    'useminPrepare',
    'postcss',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'babel:server',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `openLoginDialog.$inject = ['ev', '$mdDialog']`?

More info here: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5888

Also, in general you'll want to follow best practices: [Angularjs minify best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice)

Comment: No i am not havign any problems with dependency injection.  in the controller, if I replace the templateUrl wth template and put raw html in a string, it work fine.  The problem is, the site cannot find the path ''../../Dialogs/loginDialog/loginDialog.html'' because if minifying, that path no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem.  When the application got minified, all html and js files were pushed into one file. So all directories are now at the same level.  So my path was `../../Dialogs/loginDialog/loginDialog.html` when it should have been just `../../Dialogs/loginDialog/loginDialog.html`