# angular 2 loads too many files on refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

**EDIT 2**
this seems to be a bug.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9359

my angular 2 application (very simple one) is loading hundrets of js/html/css files when I refresh the page.

is there a way to load one bundled-file instead of all these little files because it just takes so much time...

[image]

**EDIT:**

most of the traffic Comes from the rxjs...how can I use the rxjs.min.js??

Comment: That's only during development. If you build the project the output will result in only a few files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use minify dependency from npm using gulp or grunt which will combine all the javascript files into one file.

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify

Comment: but these files are all from angular2...isn't there a way to include a already build file? otherwise development just takes to much time...

Comment: please go through [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice and ) and [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-minutes-to-min-safe-angular-code-with-grunt/) hope this may help you

Comment: These links are for angular1x..i never had Problems like that in angular1.