# TypeError: Cannot set propertly src of null after minifying the javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following line is one of my angular controller:

```
document.getElementById('someId').src = localStorageService.get('someKey');
```

It is giving me, TypeError: Cannot set propertly src of null after minifying the javascript, in my angular app. It is not happening with un-minified code.
What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: Does `someId` have a `src` in your HTML?

Comment: Yes, it has. It is meant to load an url.

Comment: Could you share the rest of your HTML/Javascript?

Comment: Did you read how to minify Angularjs? May be you will find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice

Comment: This line shouldnt be in a controller. Use a directive or a component for this. (but this does not answer your question)

Comment: Thanks all. I just figured out that after minification (as the part of build process), the html is getting modified where element with id "someId" is not present.