# Cant minify angular directive

Tags: angularjs, minify, directive

I'm having an issue minifying one of my directives.

```
(function () {
angular.module("inflightApp.bnLazySrc", [])
    .directive(
    "bnLazySrc",
    function( $window, $document) {
        // I manage all the images that are currently being
        // monitored on the page for lazy loading.
        var lazyLoader = (function() {
            // I maintain a list of images that lazy-loading
            // and have yet to be rendered.
            var images = [];
            // I define the render timer for the lazy loading
            // images to that the DOM-querying (for offsets)
            // is chunked in groups.
            var renderTimer = null;
            var renderDelay = 100;
            // I cache the window element as a jQuery reference.
            var win = $( $window );
            // I cache the document document height so that
            // we can respond to changes in the height due to
            // dynamic content.
            var doc = $document;
            var documentHeight = doc.height();
            var documentTimer = null;
            var documentDelay = 2000;
            // I determine if the window dimension events
            // (ie. resize, scroll) are currenlty being
            // monitored for changes.
            var isWatchingWindow = false;
            // ---
            // PUBLIC METHODS.
            // ---
            // I start monitoring the given image for visibility
            // and then render it when necessary.
            function addImage( image ) {
                images.push( image );
                if ( ! renderTimer ) {
                    startRenderTimer();
                }
                if ( ! isWatchingWindow ) {
                    startWatchingWindow();
                }
            }
            // I remove the given image from the render queue.
            function removeImage( image ) {
                // Remove the given image from the render queue.
                for ( var i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++ ) {
                    if ( images[ i ] === image ) {
                        images.splice( i, 1 );
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // If removing the given image has cleared the
                // render queue, then we can stop monitoring
                // the window and the image queue.
                if ( ! images.length ) {
                    clearRenderTimer();
                    stopWatchingWindow();
                }
            }
            // ---
            // PRIVATE METHODS.
            // ---
            // I check the document height to see if it's changed.
            function checkDocumentHeight() {
                // If the render time is currently active, then
                // don't bother getting the document height -
                // it won't actually do anything.
                if ( renderTimer ) {
                    return;
                }
                var currentDocumentHeight = doc.height();
                // If the height has not changed, then ignore -
                // no more images could have come into view.
                if ( currentDocumentHeight === documentHeight ) {
                    return;
                }
                // Cache the new document height.
                documentHeight = currentDocumentHeight;
                startRenderTimer();
            }
            // I check the lazy-load images that have yet to
            // be rendered.
            function checkImages() {
                // Log here so we can see how often this
                // gets called during page activity.
                console.log( "Checking for visible images..." );
                var visible = [];
                var hidden = [];
                // Determine the window dimensions.
                var windowHeight = win.height();
                var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
                // Calculate the viewport offsets.
                var topFoldOffset = scrollTop;
                var bottomFoldOffset = ( topFoldOffset + windowHeight );
                // Query the DOM for layout and seperate the
                // images into two different categories: those
                // that are now in the viewport and those that
                // still remain hidden.
                for ( var i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++ ) {
                    var image = images[ i ];
                    if ( image.isVisible( topFoldOffset, bottomFoldOffset ) ) {
                        visible.push( image );
                    } else {
                        hidden.push( image );
                    }
                }
                // Update the DOM with new image source values.
                for ( var i = 0 ; i < visible.length ; i++ ) {
                    visible[ i ].render();
                }
                // Keep the still-hidden images as the new
                // image queue to be monitored.
                images = hidden;
                // Clear the render timer so that it can be set
                // again in response to window changes.
                clearRenderTimer();
                // If we've rendered all the images, then stop
                // monitoring the window for changes.
                if ( ! images.length ) {
                    stopWatchingWindow();
                }
            }
            // I clear the render timer so that we can easily
            // check to see if the timer is running.
            function clearRenderTimer() {
                clearTimeout( renderTimer );
                renderTimer = null;
            }
            // I start the render time, allowing more images to
            // be added to the images queue before the render
            // action is executed.
            function startRenderTimer() {
                renderTimer = setTimeout( checkImages, renderDelay );
            }
            // I start watching the window for changes in dimension.
            function startWatchingWindow() {
                isWatchingWindow = true;
                // Listen for window changes.
                win.on( "resize.bnLazySrc", windowChanged );
                win.on( "scroll.bnLazySrc", windowChanged );
                // Set up a timer to watch for document-height changes.
                documentTimer = setInterval( checkDocumentHeight, documentDelay );
            }
            // I stop watching the window for changes in dimension.
            function stopWatchingWindow() {
                isWatchingWindow = false;
                // Stop watching for window changes.
                win.off( "resize.bnLazySrc" );
                win.off( "scroll.bnLazySrc" );
                // Stop watching for document changes.
                clearInterval( documentTimer );
            }
            // I start the render time if the window changes.
            function windowChanged() {
                if ( ! renderTimer ) {
                    startRenderTimer();
                }
            }
            // Return the public API.
            return({
                addImage: addImage,
                removeImage: removeImage
            });
        })();
        // ------------------------------------------ //
        // ------------------------------------------ //
        // I represent a single lazy-load image.
        function LazyImage( element ) {
            // I am the interpolated LAZY SRC attribute of
            // the image as reported by AngularJS.
            var source = null;
            // I determine if the image has already been
            // rendered (ie, that it has been exposed to the
            // viewport and the source had been loaded).
            var isRendered = false;
            // I am the cached height of the element. We are
            // going to assume that the image doesn't change
            // height over time.
            var height = null;
            // ---
            // PUBLIC METHODS.
            // ---
            // I determine if the element is above the given
            // fold of the page.
            function isVisible( topFoldOffset, bottomFoldOffset ) {
                // If the element is not visible because it
                // is hidden, don't bother testing it.
                if ( ! element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
                    return( false );
                }
                // If the height has not yet been calculated,
                // the cache it for the duration of the page.
                if ( height === null ) {
                    height = element.height();
                }
                // Update the dimensions of the element.
                var top = element.offset().top;
                var bottom = ( top + height );
                // Return true if the element is:
                // 1. The top offset is in view.
                // 2. The bottom offset is in view.
                // 3. The element is overlapping the viewport.
                return(
                    (
                        ( top <= bottomFoldOffset ) &&
                        ( top >= topFoldOffset )
                    )
                    ||
                    (
                        ( bottom <= bottomFoldOffset ) &&
                        ( bottom >= topFoldOffset )
                    )
                    ||
                    (
                        ( top <= topFoldOffset ) &&
                        ( bottom >= bottomFoldOffset )
                    )
                );
            }
            // I move the cached source into the live source.
            function render() {
                isRendered = true;
                renderSource();
            }
            // I set the interpolated source value reported
            // by the directive / AngularJS.
            function setSource( newSource ) {
                source = newSource;
                if ( isRendered ) {
                    renderSource();
                }
            }
            // ---
            // PRIVATE METHODS.
            // ---
            // I load the lazy source value into the actual
            // source value of the image element.
            function renderSource() {
                element[ 0 ].src = source;
            }
            // Return the public API.
            return({
                isVisible: isVisible,
                render: render,
                setSource: setSource
            });
        }
        // ------------------------------------------ //
        // ------------------------------------------ //
        // I bind the UI events to the scope.
        function link( $scope, element, attributes ) {
            var lazyImage = new LazyImage( element );
            // Start watching the image for changes in its
            // visibility.
            lazyLoader.addImage( lazyImage );
            // Since the lazy-src will likely need some sort
            // of string interpolation, we don't want to
            attributes.$observe(
                "bnLazySrc",
                function( newSource ) {
                    lazyImage.setSource( newSource );
                }
            );
            // When the scope is destroyed, we need to remove
            // the image from the render queue.
            $scope.$on(
                "$destroy",
                function() {
                    lazyLoader.removeImage( lazyImage );
                }
            );
        }
        // Return the directive configuration.
        return({
            link: link,
            restrict: "A"
        });

    });

}());
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem? How are you minifying this? We cannot help you without details.

Comment: `directive( "bnLazySrc", function( $window, $document) {` ==> `directive( "bnLazySrc",[ '$window', '$document', function( $window, $document)   ..... }]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs minify best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice)

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to annotate your functions with the names of the dependencies.

See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#a-note-on-minification).