# gulp build angular js error: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am trying to minify angularjs and the route files using gulp

```
var files = [
    'node_modules/angular/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js'
]

    gulp.task('libs', function () {
        return gulp.src(files)
            .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/assets/build'))
            .pipe(ngAnnotate())
            .pipe(uglify({
                mangle: false
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));

    });
```

After minificaton i got the following error in my console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

I've tried so many questions related to my issue,but that didn't solved my issue

gulp version:3.9.1

gulp uglify version:^3.0.0

**Scripts**

```
 <script src="{{asset('js/libs.js')}}" ></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/scripts.js')}}" ></script>
```

Comment: Question is related to `php` tag?

Comment: oops Its a mistake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice

Comment: @Baruch already refered this question and tried gulp-ng-annotate package but didn't solved

Comment: So, what does your `index.html` file look like? It should include `libs.js` and then your other JS files

Comment: Of course it includes both files