# Different ways to initialize AngularJS Controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I've been seeing these two ways to initialize controllers.

**First Way:**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Api', function($scope, $http, Api) {}]);
```

**Second Way:**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http, Api) {}]);
```

Are there any differences between these two? If not, which one is the "best practice"?

Comment: first one is the bestway it helps you when you minify the js files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice