# how to minify angularjs+bootstrap4 project

Tags: angularjs, minify, grunt-contrib-uglify

I created a new **angularjs** project with angularjs seed.
I added some external dependencies with bower - like **bootstrap4** and some angularjs additional modules like **ui-rout** and **ui-grid**.

The size of all the source files is about 25 Megabyte.

I want to **minify** it obviously :)

I tried doing with **grunt** and **grunt-es** and **uglify** with concatanating the files and without, and it always fails :( 
Usually with **'unexpected character'** error.

Anyone here that Minified Angularjs seed + bootstrap4 with grunt or any *other* tasks manager tool that can guide me?

Im getting really frustrated :(

**MY PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-babel": "^7.0.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify-es": "git+https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify.git#harmony",
    "grunt-dist": "0.0.6",
    "grunt-es6-transpiler": "^1.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.4.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "update-deps": "npm update",
    "postupdate-deps": "bower update",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
    "update-index-async": "node -e \"var fs=require('fs'),indexFile='app/index-async.html',loaderFile='app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js',loaderText=fs.readFileSync(loaderFile,'utf-8').split(/sourceMappingURL=angular-loader.min.js.map/).join('sourceMappingURL=bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js.map'),indexText=fs.readFileSync(indexFile,'utf-8').split(/\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/).join('//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n'+loaderText+'    //@@NG_LOADER_END@@');fs.writeFileSync(indexFile,indexText);\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

**PROJECT STRUCTRUE**
[image]

Comment: To resolve the error you would need to post a stackblitz of your setup to reproduce it

Answer (score 2):

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice)

[AngularJS has some naming conventions which seem to collide with minification:](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#a-note-on-minification)

> Since AngularJS infers the controller's dependencies from the names of
>   arguments to the controller's constructor function, if you were to
>   minify the JavaScript code for the PhoneListController controller, all
>   of its function arguments would be minified as well, and the
>   dependency injector would not be able to identify services correctly.

This plugin seems deal with the issue:
[ng-annotate](https://github.com/schmod/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate)

Comment: there is angular cli for angularjs also?

Comment: From what I understand the problem that you are referring to is in Run Time after minification is finished. Im not able to Minify at all...

Comment: you will need to post reproducable code for us to help you in this case. Show us your setup with package.json and file structure :)

Comment: added what you asked for :)