# Why my angular app works fine in debug mode and not when js bundle is optimized

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, minify

I have two applications angularjs. I had to take some pages from one to migrate to the second.
Since I activate the bundle optimization with System.Web.Optimization, the application no longer runs.
Here is the state of the console:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.9%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Dn%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A328163)%0A%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A326874)%0A%20%20%20at%20u%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A327109)%0A%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A327193)%0A%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A326368)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A326499)%0A%20%20%20at%20t%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A309792)%0A%20%20%20at%20b%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A326275)%0A%20%20%20at%20yr%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A328292)%0A%20%20%20at%20o%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30100%2Fbundles%2Fvendor.js%3Fv%3D0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1%3A1%3A316546)
>
> ```
>    at Anonymous function (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:326593)
>    at t (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:309792)
>    at b (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:326275)
>    at yr (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:328292)
>    at o (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:316546)
>    at fo (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:317026)
>    at Anonymous function (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:1121209)
>    at a (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:36555)
>    at h.add (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:36865)
>    at i.prototype.ready (http://localhost:30100/bundles/vendor.js?v=0CC4LNBLFTXMcD7A3WwKd4pdBcv7gCYsWZTADZBarKU1:1:12694)
> ```

Suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs minify best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use Strict Dependency Injection

With [Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation), code will break when minified.

From the Docs:

> ## Implicit Annotation
>
> > **Careful:** If you plan to minify your code, your service names will get renamed and break your app.

You can add an `ng-strict-di` directive on the same element as `ng-app` to opt into strict DI mode.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```

Strict mode throws an error whenever a service tries to use implicit annotations.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using Strict Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection)
- [AngularJS ng-app Directive API Reference](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/docs/api/ng/directive/ngApp)
- [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)

Comment: I already did all this... before the migration all works fine event with minified sources

Comment: The error message say `Error: $injector:unpr Unknown provider: n`. Unless you edit the question to provide more information, there is no point to re-opening the question.

Comment: it works!!!
I had to change the startup of my application temporarily so that the strict mode works: do not inject ngApp otherwise the strict mode has no effect.
I was then able to see an injection problem on a decorator with the $delegate parameter